# Sidebar button click uncaught exception

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to work out why a simple sidebar is unable to catch the "click" of the button and call another script. In the javascript console in chrome, I am getting an "uncaught" notification:

[image: error-screenshot]

Here is my apps script code:

```
function openAppointmentSidebar(){             
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('appointmentSidebar');          
  var sidebar_html = html.evaluate();      
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(sidebar_html);
}    

function setAppointmentSidebar(){      
  var ok = Browser.msgBox("opened!", Browser.Buttons.OK);
}
```

And then this is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">

  <style>
    .branding-below {
      bottom: 56px;
      top: 0;
    }
    .branding-text {
      left: 7px;
      position: relative;
      top: 3px;
    }
    .col-contain {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .col-one {
      float: left;
      width: 50%;
    }
    .logo {
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .radio-spacer {
      height: 20px;
    }
    .width-100 {
      width: 100%;
    }

  </style> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="sidebar branding-below">
       <div class="block form-group">



       <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Action</th>
    <th>Zapier Hook URL</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Not Yet</td>
    <td> <input type="text" id="cf1" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>No</td>
    <td> <input type="text" id="cf2" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td>Sale </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="cf3" /></td>
  </tr>

</table>

       <br>

       <button class="action" id="btn_submit">Save Settings</button>
       <br/>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="sidebar bottom">
      <span class="gray branding-text">Powered by</span>

    </div>

    <script>
     function dostuff(){


   google.script.run.openAppointmentSidebar();

 }

  document.getElementById("btn_submit").addEventListener("click",dostuff);

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I'm almost certain I had this working in previous sidebars but obviously something isn't quite right.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour, it's working correctly for me. I guess the HTML you provided and the sidebar created by `dostuff` are the same one, and the `click` event is basically refreshing the sidebar, right?

Comment: Try putting addListener inside window.onload to insure dom is loaded

Comment: @Iamblichus yes, the do stuff function accidentally opened the sidebar instead of the other function to display a test message box. but the sidebar isn't re-loading (the function isn't being run) and swapping to execute the other function does nothing. I've also tried adding event listener for page load but that does nothing.

 <script>
     function dostuff(){
   

   google.script.run.setAppointmentSidebar();
   
 }
 
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   document.getElementById("btn_submit").addEventListener("click",dostuff);
});
    
    </script>

Comment: Have you tried different browsers? Also, have you tried to reproduce this on a new project?